# RPi 3 with I2C as a slave, can be read by the master?

Tags: i2c, pigpio

RPI 3-B, working in pyton with PIGPIO as a slave I2C device, can be read ? I'm actually using RPi as a i2c slave, master can write on it and RPi reads the buffer successfully. But could I write something in the memory of RPi in order to be read by the master?

Answer (score 1):

There is an example of doing just that in the Python pigpio module API documentation for [bsc_i2c](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#bsc_i2c).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import pigpio

I2C_ADDR=0x13

def i2c(id, tick):
    global pi

    s, b, d = pi.bsc_i2c(I2C_ADDR)
    if b:
        if d[0] == ord('t'): # 116 send 'HH:MM:SS*'

            print("sent={} FR={} received={} [{}]".
               format(s>>16, s&0xfff,b,d))

            s, b, d = pi.bsc_i2c(I2C_ADDR,
               "{}*".format(time.asctime()[11:19]))

        elif d[0] == ord('d'): # 100 send 'Sun Oct 30*'

            print("sent={} FR={} received={} [{}]".
               format(s>>16, s&0xfff,b,d))

            s, b, d = pi.bsc_i2c(I2C_ADDR,
               "{}*".format(time.asctime()[:10]))

pi = pigpio.pi()

if not pi.connected:
    exit()

# Respond to BSC slave activity

e = pi.event_callback(pigpio.EVENT_BSC, i2c)

pi.bsc_i2c(I2C_ADDR) # Configure BSC as I2C slave

time.sleep(600)

e.cancel()

pi.bsc_i2c(0) # Disable BSC peripheral

pi.stop()
```